# How do i solve Key column 'survey_type_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a table in php but everytime i run this it keeps saying  Key column 'survey_type_id' doesn't exist in table

survey_type table

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE survey_type (
    survey_type_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    type VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(survey_type_id))";
```

survey table

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE survey(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
username VARCHAR(64), 
title VARCHAR(150), 
instructions VARCHAR(250),
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username), 
FOREIGN KEY(survey_type_id) REFERENCES survey_type(survey_type_id))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this statement, the issue should be obvious:

```
CREATE TABLE survey
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    username VARCHAR(64), 
    title VARCHAR(150), 
    instructions VARCHAR(250),
    PRIMARY KEY(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username), 
    FOREIGN KEY(survey_type_id) REFERENCES survey_type(survey_type_id)
)
```

The statement is creating a foreign key between two columns, `survey.survey_type_id` and `survey_type.survey_type_id`.

However, there isn't a column named `survey_type_id` on the `survey` table.

The statement to create the `survey` table should include a definition for the `survey_type_id` column:

```
    ...
    instructions VARCHAR(250),
    survey_type_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id), 
    ...
```

Comment: Yh i'm new to this so i appreciate your help

Comment: It's no problem, we all miss things sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You missed out `survey_type_id` column in reference table that's why you getting error.

```
CREATE TABLE survey(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
username VARCHAR(64), 
title VARCHAR(150), 
instructions VARCHAR(250),
survey_type_id INT(11),  //Missout by you please add this
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username), 
FOREIGN KEY(survey_type_id) REFERENCES survey_type(survey_type_id))
```

After Adding column http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/680d26